# What is an idiomatic Scala way to do batch processing with exceptions

Tags: scala, scala-collections, idioms

If I have an List[Try[Int]] that represents some results from a function.

```
scala> import scala.util._
scala> val result = List[Try[Int]](
      Success(1),
      Failure(new RuntimeException("first exception")),
      Success(2),
      Failure(new RuntimeException("second exception")))
```

If I just collect the success I'm hiding the exceptions

```
scala> result.collect{case Success(x)=>x}
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

I could partition but the results need to be processed further

```
scala> val res2 = result.partition(_.isSuccess)
res2: (List[scala.util.Try[Int]], List[scala.util.Try[Int]]) = (List(Success(1), Success(2)),List(Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: first exception), Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: second exception)))

scala> res2._1.collect{case Success(x)=>x}
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> res2._2.collect{case Failure(x)=>x}
res7: List[Throwable] = List(java.lang.RuntimeException: first exception, java.lang.RuntimeException: second exception)
```

And this gets even more complicated if I have a `List[Try[Option[Int]]]`.

Comment: You have not described what you actually want to do with the successes and failures. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Validation still doesn't cover the case where you want both the successes and the failures.

Answer (score 0):

How if you convert the `List[Try[Int]]`  to  `Try[List[Int]]` ?

```
import scala.util.Try

val demo = List(Try(1),Try(2))

Try(demo.map(x => x.get))
```

It will not be complicated for `List[Try[Option[Int]]]` as well.

Hope i was helpful.

Comment: This would return the first Failure found in the list. In this case the other ones are hidden and the Success(Int) results are also ignored.

Comment: Then you can just filter out the Option values like res6.filter(_.isDefined)  for res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2) and it is not complex as well.